# To reset Nim runtime array

Tags: nim-lang

How to reset e.g.

```
var d= newSeqOfCap[ int ](70)
```

after so many pushes ie. `d.add(  )`, to be as if the first empty, not ever have been pushed ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're the same person who asked [in the live chat yesterday](https://irclogs.nim-lang.org/02-03-2022.html#15:17:11)? If so I recommend reading my reply there instead of asking the same question again here.